# python как сделать нормальную кодировку

Tags: python, windows, utf-8

Выполняется в Windows 10

Есть `pythonfile.py`, в нём:

```py
a = input()
a = a + ' привет'
print(a)
```

также есть текстовый файл `text.txt`:

```
мяу
```

Из командной строки я пишу `py pythonfile.py < text.txt`
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пытался делать `.encode('utf-8')`, но получается мусор:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Открыть документ, сохранить как - кодировка ANSI, попробуйте

Comment: @Стас вот это мне уже нужно делать из питона, потому что я не буду создавать текстовый файл руками, файлы будут создаваться в `PHP`, конечно можно следить за состоянием файла, но хотелось бы что-то +- универсальное

Answer (score 1):

Используйте `decode('utf-8')`

```
f = open(path, 'rb')
info = f.read().decode('utf-8')
f.close()
print("Содержимое файла\n", info)
```

Тогда не нужно создавать файл в кодировке ANSI

2й вариант: 
Как сказал insolor, можно открыть сразу в правильной кодировке.
У вам указано `a=a.encode('utf-8')`, измените на `file = open(path, "r", encoding="utf-8")` 
Готовый вариант:

```
file = open(path, "r", encoding="utf-8")
info = file.read()
file.close()
print("Содержимое файла\n", info)
```

Comment: Если загружаемый файл текстовый, то лучше открывать его как текстовый, сразу с указанием кодировки. Тогда decode при чтении не нужно будет.

Comment: @insolor а можно в командной строке передать данные о кодировке?

Comment: @МихаилКамахин Чем вас не устраивает мой способ (в прошлом вашем вопросе), просто добавляете sys.argv[2] и всё.  Элемент 0 - путь до программы, 1 - уже использован для передачи путь, и 2 может быть для кодировки

Comment: @МихаилКамахин все можно, но лучше договориться, чтобы обе части кода (на python и php) всегда использовали одинаковую кодировку (лучше если это будет UTF-8), тогда никаких проблем с кодировкой не будет. Если у вас php скрипт возвращает файл то в одной кодировке, то в другой, то что-то не так с этим скриптом.

Comment: @insolor в моей системе создание файла в `utf-8`, но если я этот текстовый файл даю питону, то там мусор, только если кодировку текстового файла поменяю на `windows-1251`, то будет нормально

Comment: @МихаилКамахин мусор там, потому что в Windows по умолчанию кодировка Windows1252, а файл в UTF8

Comment: @МихаилКамахин, так и делайте как показано в этом ответе, а не используйте перенаправление потока ввода из файла (`<`). Если у вас всегда входной файл в UTF-8, то никаких дополнительных параметров с указанием кодировки не нужно - просто указывайте кодировку UTF-8 при открытии файла.