# Python: Кирилица и json

Tags: python, json, кириллица

Есть код:

```
import json

with open("index.json", "r") as read_file:
    data = json.load(read_file,)

print(json.dumps(data,sort_keys=False,indent=4,ensure_ascii=False,separators=(',', ': ')))
```

Есть index.json:

```
{
    "notes": [
        {
            "name":"Запись 1",
            "date": "date",
            "input": "Хеллоу",
            "tegs": ["первая","просто"]
        }
    ]
}
```

В консоли код даёт такой выхлоп:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Собственно, что с именно русским текстом и как это исправить?

Comment: А если просто строку на русском печатать?

Comment: С русским текстом все в порядке. А вот с кодировкой в консоли - нет.

Comment: Укажите кодировку при открытии файла. Похоже, что ваш исходник не в utf-8. Да и вообще не пренебрегайте этим параметром

Comment: Если написать просто строку на русском языке, то она покажется. Если проблема с кодировкой в консоли, как её решить и почему просто print('Привет') даст именно "Привет", а не крокозябру? Все файлы в кодировке utf-8. Всё перепроверил.

Comment: Попробуйте открывать файл сразу в нужной кодировке. [Этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1129271/384202), второй вариант

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18337407/13970074

Comment: @Стас Реально помогло! Создайте ответ, я поставлю, что он верный.

Comment: Этот вопрос дубликат вопроса: [python как сделать нормальную кодировку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1129263/python-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%8e-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d1%83) и его нужно удалить. Зачем плодить одинаковые вопросы и ответы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваши файлы в Windows по умолчанию создаются в кодировке Windows 1251 (полностью русифицированая кодировка, стандартная, для систем Windows на русском языке).

А Python использует Utf-8 по умолчанию. Следовательно и пытается прочитать ваш файл в Utf 8. Из за несоответствия кодировок появляютя "крякозябры".

Вам достаточно добавить `encoding="utf-8"`, например, так:

```
open(path, "r", encoding="utf-8")
```

Это укажет Python, что файл нужно преобразовать в Utf-8 и "крякозябры" пропадут.